# function doPost(e) (lanquage Apps Script) do not trigger when i send message in telegram

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, telegram-bot

This is my code without declare token.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syEBt.png)

I'm not getting a response from the bot, when i write to him.

I check that webhook, it already set.

I sent a message on behalf of the bot to myself via the url, it worked.

Before i try getting message i run script with function setWebhook.